# Looping Inside an NSArray

Tags: xcode, loops, if-statement, for-loop, nsarray

I have this array:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *firstname = [defaults objectForKey:kFirstName];
NSString *middlename = [defaults objectForKey:kMiddleName];
NSString *lastname = [defaults objectForKey:kLastName];
NSString *gender = [defaults objectForKey:kGender];
NSString *bloodtype = [defaults objectForKey:kBloodType];
NSString *civilstatus = [defaults objectForKey:kCivilStatus];
NSString *nationality = [defaults objectForKey:kNationality];

NSArray *nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, bloodtype, civilstatus, nationality, nil];
```

And I want to create a loop in the array to check the NSString objects is null or has a value.

Presently, I have this messy if statement that doesn't use the array:

```
if (([firstname length] || [middlename length] || [lastname length] || [gender length] || [bloodtype length] || [civilstatus length] || [nationality length]) == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"test1");
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` on your array, it's quite handy for this kind of task: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:

Or simply use fast enumeration:

```
for (NSString *item in nameArray)
    if ([item length])
        NSLog(@"test1");
```